# Android ignoring string from language file in runOnUiThread

Tags: android, runnable

At the start of my activity I am setting the user's language:

```
//lng is user language 
       Locale locale = new Locale(lng);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

However this is working fine for everything in my app, also for whole activity including Asynctask, doInBackground etc.

But in AsyncTask I have an exception:

```
catch (final JSONException e) {

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(),
                                R.string.Nodata,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }); }
```

and here in runOnUiThread the R.string.Nodata is getting the string from the original language, not the user defined. SO the whole activity is working with user's language except this runnable.

Can you please advice what is wrong here?

Comment: Change it to _getResources().getString(R.string.Nodata)_

Comment: aah, thank you, it is working as expected! Can you please post this as an aswer so I could accept it

Comment: `activity.getApplicationContext()` – Don't use the application `Context` there. Just use the `Activity`.

Comment: No. Brother it's okay. Just chill !!

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for this advice, I just used it like  Toast.makeText(activity,                      R.string.Nodata,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); and it is working also this way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
R.string.some_string
```

is a public final static int that is a fixed ID to a specific String in your R.java file. This is generated automatically.

```
getString(R.string.some_string)
```

returns the String referenced by the above by reading the R.java file.

So I suggest you to use second approach in your app to get string from resource file.

To resolve your problem, you can use

```
getResources().getString(R.string.Nodata)
```